# Get id of element by click(JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get `id` of element by click.

I tried to write this function

```
 $('.not-filled-button').click(function() {
    statusFilter();
});


function statusFilter() {

   // var $rows = $('#table tr');
    alert($(this).get(0).id);
}
```

But when I click button it show `undefined` in alert

If I write it like this

```
 $('.not-filled-button').click(function() {
    //statusFilter();
    alert($(this).get(0).id);
});
```

all okay

How I can make it work in 1 variant?

Comment: `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: If you're adding this element dynamically none of these answers will work. You would have to use delegation.

Comment: @Andy Wouldn't the only thing needing to change then to be the selector? i.e: `$('<closest-static-element>').on('click', '.not-filled-button', function(){...})` but the code stays the same?

Comment: Precisely my point.

Comment: @Andy ..but that doesn't effect the code inside the functions they work just as before hence all of the answers still work. OPs click event triggered so dynamic elements and delegation was never part of the question/issue for OP to begin with as far as I know.

Comment: That's why I said "If". I was covering a possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**call**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [**apply**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) in this case to apply the context to the function called. Similar to this:

```js
$('.not-filled-button').click(function() {
    statusFilter.apply(this);
});


function statusFilter() {
   // var $rows = $('#table tr');
    alert(this.id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="someButton" class="not-filled-button">click me</button>
```

---

Alternatively you can just pass the element as a parameter, similar to this:

```js
$('.not-filled-button').click(function() {
    statusFilter(this);
});


function statusFilter(element) {
   // var $rows = $('#table tr');
    alert(element.id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="someButton" class="not-filled-button">click me</button>
```

Or, as mentioned in the comments, if all you ever will call is `statusFilter` when clicked you can assign the method reference directly, similar to this:

```js
$('.not-filled-button').click(statusFilter);


function statusFilter() {
   // var $rows = $('#table tr');
    alert(this.id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="someButton" class="not-filled-button">click me</button>
```

Comment: `$('.not-filled-button').click(statusFilter);` is sufficient, No need to `call()` or `apply()`

Comment: @Satpal True, though it prevents making more calls to other methods inside the click event, I add it as an alternative as that might as well be the desired approach.

Answer (score 2):

The `this` context inside of `statusFilter` would be different,

```
$('.not-filled-button').click(function() {
  statusFilter(this);
});


function statusFilter(_this) {
  alert($(_this).get(0).id);
}
```

Or you could simply bind the context of the event listener to the function `statusFilter`

```
$('.not-filled-button').click(function() {
  statusFilter.bind(this)(); // Approach 1
  statusFilter.call(this); // Approach 2
  statusFilter.apply(this); // Approach 3
});
```

And for getting the Id of an element you could simply do,

```
function statusFilter(_this) {
  alert(_this.id);
}
```

If your event listener is not going to contain any other function call other than `statusFilter`, you can just do,

```
$('.not-filled-button').click(statusFilter);
```

Comment: Thank's. it's helps.

Comment: @Satpal I am trying to adhere with the code which OP has. Let me suggest him a better approach.

Comment: @Satpal What if OP wants to call more function like this inside the event listener?

Answer (score 0):

The `this` context isn't automatically passed into your statusFilter function. You could try passing it in as a parameter like this:

```
$('.not-filled-button').click(function() {
    statusFilter(this);
});

function statusFilter(elementReference) {
    alert($(elementReference).get(0).id);
}
```